# Is there a way to send values from actor to actorRef in ActorSystem

Tags: scala, akka

I have two actors coded as follows.

```
class Actor1 extends Actor {
    val r : ActorRef = actorOf (Props[Actor2], "master")

    def receive: Receive = {
        case class Mul (a,b) =>
            r ! CalcMul (a,b)

        case class MulReply (ans) =>
            println("Multiply result : " + ans)
            // want to send "ans" value to testObject..
    }
}

class Actor2 extends Actor {

    def receive: Receive = {
        case class CalcMul (a,b) =>
            sender ! MulReply (a*b)
    }
}

object testObject extends App {
    val a = ActorSystem("ActorSystem").actorOf(Props[Actor1], "root")

    a ! CalcMul (5, 15)
    // how to receive "ans" value here?
}
```

I am able to receive and print the result in `Actor1` but need those values in `testObject` so I can use them for future operations. Cannot have a `receive` method in `testObject` as done to receive a message in `Actor1` from `Actor2`, so cannot send them with `tell` method.

Comment: yes you can do it using ask look at this: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#ask-send-and-receive-future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to receive a response from an actor you can use ask pattern for this purpose.

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef, ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.pattern._
import akka.util.Timeout

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.duration.SECONDS


case class CalsMul(a: Int, b: Int)

  class Actor1 extends Actor {
    val r: ActorRef = context.actorOf(Props[Actor2], "master")

    def receive: Receive = {
      case req: CalsMul =>
        println("received message by Actor1")
        r forward req
    }
  }

  class Actor2 extends Actor {

    def receive: Receive = {
      case request: CalsMul =>
        println("received message by Actor2")
        Future.successful(request.a * request.b) pipeTo sender
    }
  }

  object testObject extends App {
    implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("ActorSystem")
    val a: ActorRef = system.actorOf(Props[Actor1], "root")
    implicit val timeout: Timeout = Timeout(20, SECONDS)

    println(system, "sending message to Actor1")
    val ans: Future[Int] = (a ? CalsMul(5, 15)).mapTo[Int] // as you are returning the multiplication of a*b

    ans.foreach(println)
  }
```

Note: **CPU bound operations are not advised  to use with actors it can have adverse effect on the performance of your application**

Comment: Rather, if you have CPU-bound operations, don't try to complete them with a single message. Find some way to break the problem into pieces and either hand off the work to multiple children or send yourself messages triggering the sub-tasks. Letting children split the work can take advantage of more cores; telling yourself to work on it provides the equivalent of Thread.yield() calls, as the dispatcher has an opportunity to switch the thread to a different actor between steps.

Comment: No we should not do the CPU-bound operations inside the Future becuase it not meant to made for that rather we should use Futures for I/O bond operation because these are blocking calls and can run saparately on a thread no matter how many small chunks we give to the child actor cpu bound operation in Future is not a good practices. @RobCrawford

Comment: I did not say to use a Future. I have no idea where you got the idea I did.

Comment: Ask call always return a Future, you said that don't try to complete CPU-bound operations in a single message(which is an ask message) so i got the idea of Future. @RobCrawford