# How to set construction fields or configuration loading in akka actor?

Tags: java, scala, spring-boot, akka

I have a scenario where i need to get data from Soap Service API call for each company.
For each industry i have thousands companies.

To call API , i need to set/pass few parameters apart from companyid. These parameters like user name , password , url , port etc... more of configuration or property files ..

These wont change for each call i.e. each Actor.

I am trying to implement the same using Akka Actor system for company retrieval i.e. calling Soap Service API .

Me new to Akka ,  any help how to do this ?

Thanks and Regards.

**Tried :**

CompanyActor -- which expects a companyId so created a CompanyInput as below

```
CompanyInput{
 String companyId,
 DataAPIConnection conn;
}
```

I am preparing CompanyInput where I get connection object "conn" by passing all valid userName and pwd , url to Soap Service API call.
I set companyId also.

Then create CompanyActor . where

```
@Override
        public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Throwable {
               if(msg instanceof CompanyInput) {
                   CompanyInput input = (CompanyInput)  msg;
                   logger.info("onRecive msg companyId : " + input.getCompanyId());
               }

        }
```

Hope the above works fine. Please suggest if any corrections needed.

But from this I need to return CompanyInfo object i.e. reading the fields from SoapAPI call and populating  CompanyInfo  VO.

How to return an object from an Actor call ? onReceive() returning void so I return a Future ?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in Java or Scala?

Comment: @RamanMishra Raman please checked the tried one.

Comment: @Iprakashv , Yeah my company wants it to be Java , to be more precise spring-book and java 8.

Comment: use ? (ask) it returns a Future[Object] this is how you get return value from the actor! can you provide the code where you are doing tell ! or ask ? to your actor?

Comment: @RamanMishra , any sample programs Raman ? , confused returning actual object or/and exception thrown in any case? ..

Comment: @RamanMishra , how can use "public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Throwable " ... which is turning void ? should I use anything else when used .ask method ?

Comment: see this answer of mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53323500/is-there-a-way-to-send-values-from-actor-to-actorref-in-actorsystem/53323965#53323965

Comment: @RamanMishra thank you Raman , but My actor is defined like this "" public class CompanyActor  extends UntypedActor """  should I change it ? I have only one version of onReceive() method with returning " void".. what should i use ?

Comment: it has nothing to do with the return type of Receive method it's the partial function we need to give the implementation for Receive method I don't know how it works in java but in scala we have Receive as the return type

Comment: @RamanMishra nup it is not working in java ..

Answer (score 1):

In Akka, messages go in one direction and the receive function does not return a value. Instead, you can send a reply message back to the original sender:

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#reply-to-messages

You can use the "ask pattern" to simplify sending a message that expects a reply. Calling `ask` returns a `CompletionStage` in Java (or a `Future` in Scala) that completes when the receiving actor replies to its sender:

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#ask-send-and-receive-future

Comment: thank you Tim , but if any Exception occurs while returning an object in second/called actor ...how to handle those scenarios?

Comment: can we use constructor in Actor ? For each actor instance I no need to set up configurations right ... how and where to set configuration related parameters ?

Comment: @Shyam error handling is covered in the documentation I linked to: "To complete the CompletionStage with an exception you need to send an akka.actor.Status.Failure message to the sender. This is not done automatically when an actor throws an exception while processing a message."

Comment: @Shyam creating actors is also covered in the documentation https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#creating-actors